# django redirect causes a redirect to next page, but then returns to original?

Tags: django, django-views

My redirect function is causing some issues. I call a url from a view using reverse with the parameters required for the view. There are no errors and in the browser of the url it correctly displays these parameters. However it seems like it redirects to the new url, but immediately after requesting the new view for the new url the page returns to the original view with the new url still displayed in the browser. Can anyone tell me if I am using the redirect function correctly or maybe I am using the reverse incorrectly?

P.S. I chopped out a lot of code because StackOverflow won't let me post all of it.

home/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from home import views

app_name = 'home'

urlpatterns = [
    url('^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url('^patient_summary/patientid=(?P<patient_id>\d+)&clinicid=(?P<clinic_id>\d+)/', views.patient_summary, name='patient_summary'),
    url('^patient_summary/patientid=(?P<patient_id>\d+)&clinicid=(?P<clinic_id>\d+)/careplanid=(?P<careplan_id>\d+)/', views.care_plan, name='care_plan'),
    ]
```

home/views.py

```
def patient_summary(request, token, patient_id, clinic_id):
    user = get_user(token)
    if request.method == "POST":
        if ('careplanselected' in request.POST):
            props = request.POST.get('careplan')
            props = props.split("@")
            CPID = props[0]
            cpname = props[1]
            my_dict = {'token': token, 'patient_id': patient_id, 'clinic_id': clinic_id, 'careplan_id': CPID}
            return redirect(reverse('home:care_plan', kwargs=my_dict)) 
    return render(request, 'home/patient_summary.html')

def care_plan(request, token, patient_id, clinic_id, careplan_id):
    user = get_user(token)
    care_plan = []
    cpname = '' 
    return render(request, 'home/care_plan.html' )
```

Comment: Note that you don't need to use `reverse` with `redirect` - you can do `return redirect('home:care_plan', **my_dict)`. However that's not the problem here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your URL patterns are missing dollars to mark the end of the URL. That means that your `patient_summary` view will be handling requests meant for the `care_plan` view.

Change the patterns to:

```
url('^patient_summary/patientid=(?P<patient_id>\d+)&clinicid=(?P<clinic_id>\d+)/$', views.patient_summary, name='patient_summary'),
url('^patient_summary/patientid=(?P<patient_id>\d+)&clinicid=(?P<clinic_id>\d+)/careplanid=(?P<careplan_id>\d+)/$', views.care_plan, name='care_plan'),
```